# how to implement a callback in runnable to update other swing class

Tags: java, oop

I have a thread like this

```
public class SMS {
 class Read implements Runnable {
  Read(){
   Thread th = new Thread(this);
   th.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   while (true){
     Variant SMSAPIReturnValue = SMSAPIJava.invoke("ReadSMS");
     if (SMSAPIReturnValue.getBoolean()){
      String InNumber = SMSAPIJava.getPropertyAsString("MN");
      String InMessage = SMSAPIJava.getPropertyAsString("MSG");
     }
   }
  }

 }
}
```

How do I update the message to another GUI class in the same package(I understand how to put nested class to another package ....). Should I implement a callback function in SMS class? But how? Or should I pass in the Jlabel into the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read you correctly--if you want the other class to hear an event generated in this class, you should have that class add itself as a listener to this class.

Comment: It's done the same way you add yourself as an ActionListener to a swing button. It's a good general solution and keeps your classes abstract from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the GUI components you want to update into SMS class, don't worry much about memory because it will be passed by reference, another choice is to have a singleton view class and any component you want to edit or update should have a getter function in the view class.

```
View.getSingleton().getJLabel1().setText(InNumber);
```